# Hspec: How to suppress successful test results

Tags: haskell, hspec

Is there anyway to prevent successful tests from being printed out to screen?
At the moment I have a lot of tests with really long inputs and I only really care about seeing the fails?

*Edit: I am running my tests with* `stack test`

**Solution:**

Thanks to the answer from @mb14, I was able to search for what I was looking for.

running your test file directly:

you can use:

```
runhaskell testfile.hs --format=failed-examples
```

or

```
runhaskell testfile.hs -f failed-examples
```

and to run via `stack test`:

```
stack test --test-arguments=--format=failed-examples
```

[source](https://hspec.github.io/options.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you try `--format=failed-examples` ? Also the [rerun](http://hspec.github.io/rerun.html) feature allows to only run (and therefore displays) the failing test (from the previous run).

To use it with stack, you can use the `--test-arguments` argument

```
 stack test --test-arguments --format=failed-examples
```

Or modify the `.hspec` file using `echo --format=failed-examples >> .hspec`. You can find [here](http://hspec.github.io/options.html) all the differnt ways to specify arguments hspec.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. I think you have an error and it should be `--format=failed-examples`. Can this be run with `stack test`?

Comment: Updated my answer.